# jQuery accessing iframe DOM does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code for jQUery to access the DOM inside of an iframe. But this does not work. What is the problem of the code? thanks

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#ifr').contents().find('div').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("this is a good thing");
    });
});
</script>
<iframe id='ifr' style='width: 80%; height: 600px;' src='http://tarjom.ir'></iframe>
<div style="width: 200px;height: 100px; border: 1px red solid;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The iframe has an absolute URI in the `src` attribute. That implies you are attempting to access the DOM of a page on another domain. This is forbidden for security reasons.

Comment: what should I do then if I want to access the DOM of that page. I need to count each click of the user on a banner of the displayed website

Comment: 1. Own that site. 2. Add the JS to that site.

Comment: Use a 'proxy' of sorts. Have your server side language get that page for you.

Comment: @Quentin then can you please say what sort of JS file should I include in the target website?

Comment: @MostafaTalebi — The one you have in your question (sans the bit about accessing the frame) of course.